# Get datatable's each row having input type text

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I want to get each row from the datatable of the angularjs and access value from input type text. And process further. I here populating item names from one JSON array.

[image]

I want to save this order on save button click. But how to get quantity field value for the further processing as individual for each row?

My html file code:

```
<table datatable class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr.No</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should be using ng-model for this. when binding a property to ng-model, it automatically tracks the changes that you do on a textbox. 
Ideally It should go as a property in your item object of items array
<td>
                <input type="text"  ng-model='quantity'/>
            </td>

Comment: Are you using `angular-datatables` ..? The usage of the `datatable` attr could indicate that.

Comment: Yes I am using datatable of angularjs

Comment: @Laxminarayan - but you are not initialising the datatable? How does your script looks like? I ask because if you use dataTables correct, it is very easy to extract the dynamic values of the inputs in a click handler like `save()`.

Comment: @davidkonrad how to initialize it. I initialized it by $("#orderTbl").dataTable({
   "bPaging":   false,
      "bOrdering": false,
      "bInfo":     false,
      "bFilter":     false
  });
but it's giving error like Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Comment: @Laxminarayan, since you want to render with `ng-repeat` you must follow this guide -> **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay** and remeber to use `datatable="ng"`.  Initialising with `dataTable()` / `DataTable()` is doomed to fail.